# Heroku installs wrong JDK version

Tags: java, heroku

I added `system.properties` file with the content `java.runtime.version=11` to my application like described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version), committed the changes and pushed afterwards with `git push heroku master`

unfortunately, Heroku still installs JDK 1.8:

```
...
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.3.9... done
...
...
...
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project my-module-persistence: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

What further/other steps do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and want to post my solution here.

Make sure your **system.properties** file is in your root directory.
Do not confuse this file with application.properties inside src/main/resources.